# Certain textures don't work as particle textures?

Tags: texturing, particles, blender-internal-render-engine

I can't seem to use point-density or voxel data textures to affect particles.
For example, I can set up a point-density texture that will create volumetric density around particles from system A, but if particle system B is set to use the same texture for particle emission density, nothing will be emitted.
A bit of experimenting showed that particle emission treated all points in the point density texture as position 0 on the colourramp.

Comment: what render engine are you using? cycles or BI?

Comment: BI, cycles doesn't allow particle textures.